# Help with the temp on my crock pot

Tags: temperature, crockpot

My  Rival Crock Pot doesn't have a high / low (word wise) setting, it only shows me one line or two.  I've misplaced my manual and can't for the life of me remember which is high and which is low...any help would be great.

Comment: I suggest putting a cup or two of water in on "one line" for a while and check the temperature, then turn to "two lines" and check the temperature.  Whichever feels hotter is high :)

Comment: They have many of the manuals online in PDF forms [here](http://www.rivalproducts.com/service-and-support/product-support/instruction-manuals/instruction-manuals.html).

Comment: It would be very strange to have more lines represent a lower setting.

Answer (score 3):

The Rival Crock Pot manuals are available online at this link:

https://www.manualslib.com/products/Rival-Crock-Pot-3100-3970921.html

You can always look up your specific or similar pots and confirm the settings with these posted manuals.

In looking through these, the general norm appears to be that as you turn the top of the dial to the right, you increase the temperature, and as you turn it to the left, you decrease it. Also settings of II and III are usually hotter than I.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I started apple butter in the crock pot.  It was on “l” for 10 hours.  This is definitely a low setting.
It now needs to be on high for 2 hours to finish thickening....The next turn to the right is “ll” the apple mix has started to boil, definitely high.

There are only two settings, so the suggestion of turning the knob to the right to increase heat was correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I follow what others have said...the more you turn to the right, the higher the temp (except for Keep Warm ~~).  1 for low, 11 for high, etc.  The manual does not specifically address this Q.
I know this reply is late but others may have the same q.